# Links menu item Throws Server 500 error

Tags: content-editor

I am trying to view items linked to a template in the master database but nothing is ever shown.

Looking at the Request / Response in developer tools gives the following stacktrace

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ownerItem]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName) +63
   Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field..ctor(ID fieldID, Item ownerItem) +113
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Links.GalleryLinksForm.GetLinkTooltip(Item reference, ItemLink link) +314
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Links.GalleryLinksForm.RenderReferences(StringBuilder result, List`1 references) +404
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Links.GalleryLinksForm.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +782

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +594
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4498
```

Does anyone know why the owner item would be null as I suspect it should actually be the template or am I way off ?

Edit: the request is :

```
 http://sitecoredev/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=Gallery.Links&id=%7BF8F7723E-B13E-45D5-8C5A-DD39A588DEC8%7D&la=en&vs=1&db=master&sc_content=master&ShowEditor=1&Ribbon.RenderTabs=true
```

and the id param is the template id.

Answer (score 5):

This issue has been fixed in Sitecore 7.2 update 6 and Sitecore 8.1 Update 2.

The support issue that contains a hotfix is `452241`. You can request the fix from Sitecore Support. Or alternatively, you can follow the instructions below.

To fix the issue in Sitecore 8.1 (pre Update 2):

1) Download the hotfix here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l36zqhwjtahl4q2/Sitecore.Support.452241.dll?dl=0

2) Put `Sitecore.Support.452241.dll` into the `bin` folder of your solution.

3) Replace one line in `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Galleries\Links\Gallery Links.xml` from:

```xml
<CodeBeside Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Links.GalleryLinksForm,Sitecore.Client"/>
```

To:

```xml
<CodeBeside Type="Sitecore.Support.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Links.GalleryLinksForm,Sitecore.Support.452241"/>
```

Comment: Sorry I never managed to get the patch applied to the server in question. I think it may have been updated to 8.2 this weekbut since Im in another team I no longer have access. Thanks for the reply though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe related to this [Sitecore community question The links gallery is broken in Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151207.](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/2912)

But I need to obtain the patch and apply it to confirm.